# why does some Google Sheet show a "file size"?

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive

I thought all Google Sheets don't take up storage quota. What does this mean?

[image: clip]

There are no picture clips or anything additional to the last file than the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google changed the Google Drive storage policy. Old files that have not edited recently  will not count against the quota but new files and edited recently files will do. For details see [Changes to Google Workspace storage policies starting June 1, 2021](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2020/11/changes-to-google-workspace-storage.html)

---

In the specific case shown in the screenshot, the files no counting against the storage quota have not been modified this year the one that is, it was edited this month.

Comment: thanks for the response. what about known large files that are active that have a "0 bytes"  file size?

Comment: You are welcome. I suggest you to post a new question including more details about that file including who owns the file, the file location, the file type, when the file was created, last modified. p.s maybe only google will be able to answer what exactly is happening with a specific file.